# Issue with workbox 2.1.0 precaching

Tags: gulp, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am using workbox 2.1.0 for generating service worker and need to precache some files from the assets directory (say index.html and clear.png) of the server and one file from a CDN (say https://akamai.com/dummy/path/app.js).
I am using gulp for building. This is how the code goes

```
gulp.task('sw', () => {
      return wbBuild.generateSW({
          globDirectory: '.',
          swDest: 'sw_gulp_generated.js',
          staticFileGlobs: [
              'index.html',
              'clear.png'
              ],          
          verbose: true,
  })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Service worker generated.');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('[ERROR] This happened: ' + err);
      });
    });
```

So, this works fine and the generated service worker has both the files in the precache list, here it goes:

```
const fileManifest = [
  {
    "url": "index.html",
    "revision": "b6eb7cd7599ed6584a715cdfc75a81c0"
  },
  {
    "url": "clear.png",
    "revision": "e17de36d2c2ddf7b068892fa4678cd31"
  },

];
const workboxSW = new self.WorkboxSW();
workboxSW.precache(fileManifest);
//more code follows ...
```

I tested and it works perfectly

Now, the **question is**: How do I add the third asset (https://akamai.com/dummy/path/app.js) in the precache list. I tried putting it in `staticFileGlobs` but it errors out saying:

```
One of the glob patterns doesn't match any files
```

Obviously because it tries to find the file https://akamai.com/dummy/path/app.js inside the `globDirectory` and can't find it.

**So, basically, how can I have the CDN URL injected in the precache list of the generated service worker while using gulp(or any build tool)?**

Comment: I tried editing the generated service worker to include https://akamai.com/dummy/path/app.js in the precache list, and it worked

`const fileManifest = [ { 
"url": "index.html", 
"revision": "b6eb7cd7599ed6584a715cdfc75a81c0" }, { 
"url": "https://akamai.com/dummy/path/app.js&quot;, 
"revision": "577cd1b1345e3676cc5a4e2acce85191" }, { 
"url": "clear.png", 
"revision": "e17de36d2c2ddf7b068892fa4678cd31" } ];

const workboxSW = new self.WorkboxSW(); 
workboxSW.precache(fileManifest);`

The question remains that how to achieve it during build process of Gulp?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like [generateSW](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/v2.1.2/packages/workbox-build/src/lib/generate-sw.js) accepts custom `precache` rules. You can pass a [runtimeCaching](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/prerelease/module-workbox-build#.Configuration) option though. It'll only cache the third-party files if they are requested by the client. Since it's a third-party request if the request results in an error response the error response will be cached and [not updated](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests#force_caching_of_opaque_responses).

```
wbBuild.generateSW({
  globDirectory: '.',
  swDest: 'sw_gulp_generated.js',
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'index.html',
    'clear.png'
  ],          
  verbose: true,
  runtimeCaching: [{
    urlPattern: 'https://exapmle.com/file.min.js',
    handler: 'staleWhileRevalidate',
    options: {
      cacheableResponse: {
        statuses: [0],
      },
    },
  }]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I think that will work, but app.js is in the critical rendering path of the webApp, so having it pre-cached will be ideal I think. Still, with the constraint we have with wbBuild, I think I might need to go with runtimeCaching instead for now.